# Static code memory leak detection for visual studio vc++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, memory-leaks, static-analysis

is there a way to detect simple memory leaks like this one with a static analysis tool? I cannot change the code to include the tipical includes used in runtime memory leak detection (struc1 is a simple structure with some fields).

```
void noRelease(void)
{
    struc1 *memoryLeak;

    memoryLeak = (struc1 *) malloc(sizeof struc1);
    if (NULL != memoryLeak)
    {
        memoryLeak->a=3;
    }
}
```

VSTS (Visual Studio Team System) detects memory leaks due to exceptions but is not able to see this simple leak.

Any ideas will be very helpful. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nobody would ever write code like this.  That you *can* write code like this doesn't mean that somebody would find it profitable to write a tool to detect it.  It isn't profitable.

Comment: @Hans: of course, almost nobody would write code like that. This is a proof of concept only. If a tool can not detect this one of course it wont detect much harder leaks.

Comment: @Hans - The problem is that LOTS of people have written code like, and too much code like this is still floating around unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... Coverity could do that but you would have to sell your house to pay for it.
I once wrote a static analyzer that checks if a pair of functions are called in a given function scope. I used a static analysis API that comes with a program called 'Understand 4 C++' made by scitools.
www.scitools.com
I wrote the searcher/scrutinzer using a [managed API](http://understandapi.codeplex.com/) (that I wrote) that wraps their C API. Note: However Understand 4 c++ is not free.

Anyways, that tool I wrote would detect the lack of free in the code above. it was not much smarter than that. If the pointer was free'd somewhere else, it would not find it.

Answer (score 2):

CPPCheck does static code analysis and detect those kind of leaks

http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/